# "reset the north direction of my life" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The 7 habits have taught me profound truths that transcend because they are based on principles. They have helped me see what I cannot see.  In every situation I can use the principles and paradigms associated with each habit, think over and ***reset the north direction of my life***.

The phrase seems to be used metaphorically, but I'm not sure what it means exactly.  Is "the north direction" referring to ***the right direction***?

Comment: Note: for geological reasons, magnetic north is a slowly moving point, unlike true north, and compass settings/readings have to allow for the difference between them. In this sense, they are reset - possibly the metaphor the writer is using.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_magnetic_pole

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Can it mean "the writer could find the right direction" in every situation(because he could reset the north direction of his life)? That means he could always find the way out in every situation. Does this interpretation make some sense?